# Include a client side npm dependency in development only in a Vue CLI app

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I'm wondering if it's possible to include an npm dependency in my client-side code, but only in development.

I have some API mocking code that I only want to run in development:

```js
// src/main.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import { Server } from "miragejs";

Vue.config.productionTip = false

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  new Server()
}

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

I would like the npm dependency `miragejs` to get tree-shaken from my production build, as well as the code in the development block.

Is this possible? Alternatively, is there a more idiomatic way to only include certain npm assets in certain environments?

Comment: Do you use `vue-cli`?

Comment: What about using npm devDependency?

Comment: Yep, I use `vue-cli`. I'm a Vue noobie but did look through the docs.

Comment: @MartinT is that all it takes? What about my `import { server } from 'miragejs'`, wouldn't that throw an error in a production build if it's not stripped out or shimmed?

Comment: Well, it is the same as with unit tests for example. You just have to make sure, it is isolated from production code.

Comment: @MartinT Are there any sort of "initializers" in Vue CLI where I can run some code in development environment only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop down to your `vue.config.js` file (similar to a `webpack.config.js`!) and override parts of your config. You can either mess with loaders, or concat some files in the beginning.

You have two options: `chainWebpack` or `configureWebpack` (if `process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'PRODUCTION'`)

- `configureWebpack` takes in an object literal. I found that simpler as a beginner.
- `chainWebpack` is a function that returns a modified config. It has a pretty complex API [(here)](https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain)

[vue-cli docs for both of those options](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#configurewebpack)

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
    // sometimes I just require my webpack files here...
    // require('./webpack.config.js')
    // There are some webpack config merge plugins available, I don't remember the names of them.
    configureWebpack: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'PRODUCTION' ? devOnlyConfig : {},
    chainWebpack: (config) => {
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'PRODUCTION') { /* modify config! */ }
        return config;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Something like this ended up working: https://github.com/miragejs/site/issues/103

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late but the way I am doing it in my own Vue.js applications is

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  const { SERVER } = require('miragejs'); // instead of import
  new Server();
}
```